# How to get translated term name from TID in views field template?

Tags: views, 8, theming

For a complex view, I need to alter the output of a localized term field: instead of putting out the TID of the term, I would like to render the localized term name.
Does someone know how to alter the `{{ output -}}` in template file views-view-field.html.twig?

Comment: It's a bit late for that, at this point the field output is finally rendered. This should be possible to configure in Views UI with a relationship to taxonomy.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was looking for a workaround because of this obstacle/issue in views: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/281051/taxonomy-terms-not-localized-in-view-with-enabled-aggregation