# Taxonomy terms not localized in view with enabled aggregation

Tags: views, 8, i18n-l10n

On a view on content, I added a field "All taxonomy terms" (Display all taxonomy terms associated with a node from specified vocabularies) and enabled aggregation, see screenshot of view attached. This view is listing exclusively terms that are actually used in content.
While the view is working for the standard language of the site, the terms are not translated into the other languages despite the vocabulary is translatable.
Once I disable the aggregation, the translation of terms is working again.

So how can I make the translation of terms work?

[image]

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: In the end i removed aggregation and wrote my custom module, which one removes views dublicates.